# Use Fubini Theorem for compute $\int_F\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: measure-theory

Use Fubini Theorem for compute $\displaystyle\int_F\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}}$ where $F$ is the region bounded with the function: $y=\frac{x^2}{2}$ and the straight $x=0$, $x=2$.

In what order is better integrate?

I don know how solve this exercise. can someone help me?

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say that $x=0$ should instead be $y=0.$  In that case, you should integrate with respect to $x$ first.

Comment: Observe that you have $xdx=d(1+x^2+y^2)/2$ for fixed $y$. Integration in $x$ is thus immediate. Then you are left with the integration of $\sqrt{A^2+y^2}$ w.r.t. $y$, which can be done with the substitution $y=A\sinh t$, for example.